# How can I use sed to make thousands of substitutions in a file using a reference file?

Tags: database, bash, dictionary, awk, sed

I have a big file with two columns like this:

```
 tiago@tiago:~/$ head Ids.txt 
 TRINITY_DN126999_c0_g1_i1 ENSMUST00000040656.6
 TRINITY_DN126999_c0_g1_i1 ENSMUST00000040656.6
 TRINITY_DN126906_c0_g1_i1 ENSMUST00000126770.1
 TRINITY_DN126907_c0_g1_i1 ENSMUST00000192613.1
 TRINITY_DN126988_c0_g1_i1 ENSMUST00000032372.6
 .....
```

and I have another file with data, like this:

```
"baseMean" "log2FoldChange" "lfcSE" "stat" "pvalue" "padj" "super" "sub" "threshold"
"TRINITY_DN41319_c0_g1" 178.721774751278 2.1974294626636 0.342621318593487 6.41358066008381 1.4214085388179e-10 5.54686423073089e-08 TRUE FALSE "TRUE"
"TRINITY_DN87368_c0_g1" 4172.76139849472 2.45766387851112 0.404014016558211 6.08311538160958 1.17869459181235e-09 4.02673069375893e-07 TRUE FALSE "TRUE"
"TRINITY_DN34622_c0_g1" 39.1949851245197 3.28758092748061 0.54255370348027 6.05945716781964 1.3658169042862e-09 4.62597265729593e-07 TRUE FALSE "TRUE"
.....
```

I was thinking of using sed to perform a translation of the values in the first column of the data file, using the first file as a dictionary.

That is, considering each line of the data file in turn, if the value in the first column matches a value in the first column of the dictionary file, then a substitution would be be made; otherwise, the line would simply be printed.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What if the data file contains a key not present in Ids.txt?

Comment: than it should keep unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn your first file `Ids.txt` into a sed script:

```
$ sed -r 's| *(\S+) (\S+)|s/^"\1/"\2/|' Ids.txt > repl.sed
$ cat repl.sed
s/^"TRINITY_DN126999_c0_g1_i1/"ENSMUST00000040656.6/
s/^"TRINITY_DN126999_c0_g1_i1/"ENSMUST00000040656.6/
s/^"TRINITY_DN126906_c0_g1_i1/"ENSMUST00000126770.1/
s/^"TRINITY_DN126907_c0_g1_i1/"ENSMUST00000192613.1/
s/^"TRINITY_DN126988_c0_g1_i1/"ENSMUST00000032372.6/
```

This removes leading spaces and makes each line into a substitution command.

Then you can use this script to do the replacements in your data file:

```
sed -f repl.sed datafile
```

... with redirection to another file, or in-place with `sed -i`.

If you don't have GNU sed, you can use this POSIX conformant version of the first command:

```
sed 's| *\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)|s/^"\1/"\2/|' Ids.txt
```

This uses basic instead of extended regular expressions and uses `[^ ]` for "not space" instead of `\S`.

Comment: Based on the problem description, it would be more efficient and probably safer if the lines in repl.sed looked like this: s/^"..../"....

Comment: using parallel to run all 6 files took 15 minutes to complete

Answer (score 1):

Since the first file (the dictionary file) is large, using `sed` may be very slow; a much faster and not much more complex approach would be to use `awk` as follows:

```
awk -v col=1 -v dict=Ids.txt '
  BEGIN {while(getline<dict){a["\""$1"\""]="\""$2"\""} } 
  $col in a {$col=a[$col]}; {print}'
```

(Here, "Ids.txt" is the dictionary file, and "col" is the column number of the field of interest in the data file.)

This approach also has the advantage of not requiring any modification to the dictionary file.

Comment: indeed, it is way too faster than sed.

Comment: @TiagoBruno - Could you please be more specific?  Actually, it would be interesting (and perhaps useful for some) to have timings for (a) the awk solution; (b) the sed solution as (originally) posted; and (c) the sed solution modified to use `s/^".../.../` instead of just `s/".../.../`.

Comment: I will post the times took for of each solution here soon.

Comment: Testing on some dummy files showed a speedup of a factor 2-3 in favour of awk, but as you say, with a large dictionary file, this will probably be much bigger. Looking forward to the measurements on the real data!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Declare hash table
declare -A Ids

# Go though first input file and add key-value pairs to hash table
while read Id; do
    key=$(echo $Id | cut -d " " -f1)
    value=$(echo $Id | cut -d " " -f2)
    Ids+=([$key]=$value)
done < $1

# Go through second input file and replace every first column with
# the corresponding value in the hash table if it exists
while read line; do
    first_col=$(echo $line | cut -d '"' -f2)
    new_id=${Ids[$first_col]}

    if [ -n "$new_id" ]; then
        sed -i s/$first_col/$new_id/g $2
    fi
done < $2
```

I would call the script as

```
./script.sh Ids.txt data.txt
```

Comment: Running `cut` once and `sed` twice for each line of input will be monumentally slow by comparison with running `sed` twice, once to create the `sed` script and then once to run the `sed` script.  If there were only a couple of lines to change, it wouldn't matter much, but there are thousands of them.

Comment: Well, that depends on whether or not the sed script is able to edit the file in one pass, which I don't assume is the case (?). If every `s/xxx/yyy/` line causes `sed` to traverse the data file then it's one pass per id. I edited my code to remove an unnecessary `sed` when getting `first_col`, but of course it still does `sed` and `cut` once per iteration.

Comment: `sed` is a (the?) 'stream editor'.  It applies the actions in its script to each line of input in turn.  It can handle arbitrarily large data files; older versions of `sed` may have problems with large enough `sed` scripts, but most modern versions of `sed` have lost the limitations of older versions.

Comment: Okay, I did the math. Given n = (Lines in data files), m = (Lines in ID file), the sed script goes though the data file line-by-line, applying each `s/xxx/yyy/` once, so a complexity of n × m. My script goes though the data file once but does substitutions again on the data file, so n × n complexity. Given n >> m, my script has a worse computational complexity, but if m ≈ n or even m > n then my script should only be slower if `cut` takes a very long time of it there is some penalty to restarting `sed` on each iteration.

Comment: I think the true penalty is Bash loops being super slow.